# puppet network module for sub-interface

Tags: linux, interface, puppet

I am new in puppet and i have just installed network module from [razorsedge/network](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/razorsedge/network) but i don't know where to put `ipaddress` and `netmask` info etc.

Here is what i did

```
[root@puppetmaster manifests]# ls -l /etc/puppet/modules/network/manifests
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 puppet puppet 4096 Jan 16 14:50 alias
-r--r--r-- 1 puppet puppet 1420 Jan 16 15:31 alias.pp
drwxr-xr-x 2 puppet puppet 4096 Jan 16 14:50 bond
drwxr-xr-x 2 puppet puppet 4096 Jan 16 14:50 bridge
-r--r--r-- 1 puppet puppet 2363 Aug 18 20:57 global.pp
drwxr-xr-x 2 puppet puppet 4096 Jan 16 14:50 if
-r--r--r-- 1 puppet puppet 3564 Aug 18 20:57 init.pp
-r--r--r-- 1 puppet puppet 1423 Aug 18 20:57 route.pp
```

I have edit file `alias.pp` and put following info end of the file.

```
# define network::alias

network::alias { 'eth0:0':
        ensure    => 'up',
        ipaddress => '10.3.68.98',
        netmask   => '255.255.224.0'
}
```

my `node.pp`

```
node client01 {
        include ntp
        include network::alias
}
```

when i am running puppet on client i am getting following error `Could not find class network::alias` ???

```
[root@client01 ~]# puppet agent --test --noop
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class network::alias for client01 on node client01
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have edit file alias.pp and put following info end of the file.

You don't edit the alias.pp file to create an interface.  You create a network::alias resource  in your node definition:

```
node client01 {
  include ntp
  network::alias { 'eth0:0':
    ensure    => 'up',
    ipaddress => '10.3.68.98',
    netmask   => '255.255.224.0'
  }
}
```

network::alias is a defined resource, allowing you to create multiple instances of it.  It's not a class that can be included.